# Using custom email field for send in triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, custom-field, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

i'm helping a company who already has salesforce implemented with triggered sends.

The thing is they need to send to a custom email field instead of the standard email field. When creating a trigger send it just let's me select the object which has the email, but not change what the email field is.

Is it possible to change the email to which a triggered (or all triggered emails) sends?

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe consider using Journey Builder in conjunction with ["Salesforce Data" as the entry event](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/). Journey Builder allows you to specify the email to use within the interaction and that email isn't necessarily that of the Contact/Lead.

[image]

Comment: Do i have to ask to get salesforce data activated? I dont have it default in my org. And ty!

Comment: BTW if i use journey builder can i still send by record owner? Customer has around 900 users, it'd be hard to get a send profile for each.

Comment: No. Not normally. You'd need to have version 5.496 or higher of Marketing Cloud Connect is required, though.

Comment: Oh, then i cant work with that :/ guess ill have to come up for a fix in salesforce. I have marketing cloud connect 208.2, which as far as i know is the latest release. TYVM

Comment: Sender Profile is a separate question, but as you're setting up the data you pass over to the Entry Event data extension, make sure you include the user's Display Name and Email Address, so that it can be used for personalisation in SFMC. Then you'd need to create a "Dynamic Sender Profile" - https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/how_to_use_sender_profiles_and_data_extensions_to_send_emails_from_multiple_email_addresses/

Comment: Sorry. Missed your comment about version. You're on a new version. Just to check... Create a new Journey Builder interaction. In the "EntrySources" on the left activities panel, do you see "Salesforce Data". If not, drop a case to Support.